# C++ Override a pure virtual method with reference to an abstract class as a parameter by method that takes non abstract sub-class as parameter

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have the following code:

```
struct A{ f()=0; };
struct Aa : A{ f(){} };
struct B{
   void foo(A&)=0;
};
struct Bb : B{
   void foo(Aa&);
};
```

Right now I can't create a `Bb` class instance since I didn't override `foo` from class `B` with demanded parameter.  How can I make it work?

Comment: What do you expect to happen, if `foo` is called through a `B&` and the argument's dynamic type is not `Aa`?

Comment: Those methods have different signatures, so it's not an override. And what exactly would you expect to happen if someone tried `A someA; Bb someBb; someBb.foo(someA);`? (Or, if you object that `A` is an abstract base class, `Ab someA;` where `Ab` is a different concrete class that derives publically from `A`.)

Comment: For it to work (for supported languages), you would need contra-variance, so `B::foo(Aa&) = 0`, `Bb::foo(A&)`. And C++ is one of the language which support contra-variance.

Comment: C++ supports covariance of return type (with pointer or reference) though (`Base* Base::clone() const;`, `Derived* Derived::clone() const override;`).

Comment: Right now i don't have any other classes that inherits from A, so is it a good idea to just add separate function in class Bb that makes nothing? If i had Ab , Ac ... classes i d like them to have different behavior. (I know that maybe using polymorphism here in a situation when i have just one class that inherits, is little abuse, but this project that i make is only made to get to know some polymorphic behaviors)

Comment: What do you think `f()=0;` does?

Comment: If possible, just make it so that `Bb` takes an `A&` and uses that interface. It can use `A::f()` and exactly what happens will depend on how the concrete class overrides `f`. If you find `Bb` needs to care about the exact dynamic type of the class above and beyond that, that suggests some design issues with your inheritance structure.

Comment: Can you show a real-world usage example?

Comment: If you don't plan on having any other classes that inherit from `A`, then you don't need `A`. But if you will later have classes that inherit from `A`, you need to incorporate that possibility into your design. Please take the time to think about the question I posed in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it work?

You cannot make it work without changing the premises. `void(Aa&)` cannot override `void(A&)`. The parameter types must match.

---

Generally in object oriented programming, an overriding function cannot never have more strict parameter type.

<sub>Some object oriented languages support contravariant parameters in derived functions, which allows overriding with a function that accepts a more general parameter. For example, member function accepting `A&` could override a member function accepting `Aa&` (i.e. other way around compared to your attempt). However, C++ does not support contravariant parameters. The parameter types must match exactly.</sub>

---

Perhaps dynamic polymorphism isn't what you need. Perhaps you need static polymorphism (templates):

```
template<
    std::derived_from<A> TA
    // or if you don't have concepts:
    // class TA
>
struct B{
   void foo(TA&) {
       // use somehow
   }
};

using Bb = B<Aa>;
```

Answer (score 1):

lets assume it is possible/compiles and add extra class:

```cpp
struct A{ void f()=0; };

struct Aa : A{ int x; void f(){} };
struct Ab : A{ double x; void f(){} };

struct B{
   void foo(A&)=0;
};
struct Bb : B{
   void foo(Aa&);
};
```

Now how this should work?

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<B> p = std::make_unique<Bb>;
Ab a;
p->foo(a); // ???
```

how overridden function `Bb::foo` should handle this scenario? It expected something of type `Aa`, but got `Ab` which is not child of `Aa`. From `B::foo` perspective this call is perfectly fine since `Ab` is child of `A`.

This should give you a hint why compiler didn't do what you have expected.

Answer (score 0):

From `[class.virtual]/2` (C++17 N4713)

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly
> from Base, a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (11.3.5), cv-qualification, and
> ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it
> is so declared) and it overrides<sup>112</sup> Base::vf. For convenience we say that any virtual function overrides itself.

Now, in this case, the note 112 is actually important.

> 112. A function with the same name but a different parameter list (Clause 16) as a virtual function is not necessarily virtual **and does not override.**

In your case, you have the same name, but different parameter lists; thus you are not overriding, and are instead overloading.